# Can I log in on the Loading Screen of the PersistedGate? Redux-Presist

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-persist

I'm developing an App using redux-persist. What I want to do is a create SplashScreen where I can get the user's token and log in and then navigate.
At the moment I have a PersistedGate wrapping my `<App/>` Component with a prop named loading where you can pass a screen which will be visible while Redux is getting the persisted state.

My question is, can I use this loading screen from the PersistedGate to program what I wanted to do on my SplashScreen?

This is my index.js

```javascript
const store = configureStore();
const persistor = configurePersistor(store);

const RNRedux = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
            <App />
        </ PersistGate>
    </Provider>

);
```

Comment: the loading screen will go away when the redux-persist terminate the rehydration of the store so, i guess it is not the right place to do so.

Comment: It's unclear what the problem you are trying to solve is. Redux-persist is not really for UX. It's for persisting the state. Typically rehydration is quite fast, so you might not need a splash screen for that. Maybe it would be easier to understand your problem if you included a code sample in your question.

Comment: I edited the question. Here you can see de loading = null, but either if I put null or a screen component, the result is the same. Do you know why?